# GroupBy in LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, linq-to-sql

I need to group the table according to the Month in the table.

The query goes this way:

```
var query =
    from a in db.Dates
    from b in db.Facts
    where a.Count_Key == b.Date_key
    select new
    {
        a.Month,
        b.Fact_key
    };
```

From this query I try to group by Month

```
query = query.GroupBy(x => x.Month);
Grid1.DataSource = query;
Grid1.DataBind();
```

Then I get the following error which says:

> Cannot implicitly convert IGrouping
>   int ?  into IQueryable

Comment: And what happens? Do you get an error or does it not work?

Comment: At what point in the code do you get the error?

Comment: I hope this example can help <http://www.arpitkhandelwal.com/2011/10/grouping-in-linq-c.html>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
var query2 = query.GroupBy(x => x.Month);
Grid1.DataSource = query2;
Grid1.DataBind();
```

The problem is caused because the `var query` is implicitly inferred from its usage. The `query` is of type `IQueryable<SomeAnonymousType>` and the `GroupBy` method returns an `IQueryable<IGrouping<int?, SomeAnonymousType>>`. Those are simply two different types.

Comment: If I do that , I get this error : "A field or property with the name 'Key' was not found on the selected data source."

Comment: @Nishanth: But in this case you don't get an C# compiler error, is it? This new error is thrown by the ASP.NET GridView control.

Comment: Yes, it is thrown by the grid

Answer (score 1):

You can't reassign back to the query variable as the results of those two queries are different types.

Your first query is essentially this:

```
IQueryable<'a> query =
    from a in db.Dates
    from b in db.Facts
    where a.Count_Key == b.Date_key
    select new
    {
        a.Month,
        b.Fact_key
    };
```

I.e. it returns a straight `IQueryable` of the anonymous type.

Your second query returns an `IQueryable<IGrouping<'a>>`, i.e. an `IQueryable` of a group of the anonymous type:

```
IQueryable<IGrouping<'a>> groupedQuery = query.GroupBy(x => x.Month);
```

Therefore because the return types are different you can't assign the result of the grouping back to the original variable.